# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with enough space on heap?

Tags: java, heap-memory

We have a legacy proprietary application (Java 1.6, 32-bit) running on a modern server frequently crashing with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requestex x bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?`

While several of the `hs_err_pidxxx.log` state that the heap is exhausted there are few crashes I'm unable to explain.

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 836008 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.cpp:218), pid=6124, tid=29668
#  Error: Chunk::new
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (11.0-b16 mixed mode windows-x86)

[...]

Heap
PSYoungGen      total 167424K, used 86324K [0x5ce30000, 0x67860000, 0x67860000)
  eden space 163392K, 50% used [0x5ce30000,0x61e8fca8,0x66dc0000)
  from space 4032K, 99% used [0x67470000,0x6785d720,0x67860000)
  to   space 5440K, 0% used [0x66dc0000,0x66dc0000,0x67310000)
PSOldGen        total 1394496K, used 731399K [0x07c60000, 0x5ce30000, 0x5ce30000)
  object space 1394496K, 52% used [0x07c60000,0x346a1e30,0x5ce30000)
PSPermGen       total 65536K, used 52314K [0x03c60000, 0x07c60000, 0x07c60000)
  object space 65536K, 79% used [0x03c60000,0x06f768d0,0x07c60000)
```

1. Why does this crash?
   Doesn't *eden* has enough space for the requested 836008 bytes?
2. And should it move directly to *oldgen* if there's not enough space in *eden* and the *survivor* spaces left?
3. Is it normal that the *oldgen* is roughly 8 times bigger than the *younggen*?

VM args are only `-Xms=1529` and `-Xmx=1529`.

Comment: maybe you would like to set them to -Xms=1529m and -Xmx=1529m

Comment: You write that you are running it with a 32 bit JVM. AFAIR that means that everything (heap, perm gen, code) had to fit into 2GB. It could be that the JVM needs more (non-heap) memory and cannot allocate it because the full 2GB are already allocated. That would align with the free heap-memory and the strange error message about Chunk::new, which both indicate that the heap-memory is not the problem. Two possible solutions: Either run it with **less** heap memory (-Xmx=1200m) or run it on a 64bit JVM

Comment: Does make sense.Are there any disadvantages to set Xms = Xmx?

Comment: I don't think there are any disadvantages in your case (where you need the memory)

Comment: 1) ` -Xms=1529` means 1529 *bytes*. Which won't happen obviously, but the allowed minimum will be used, some megabytes. 2) *Oracle recommends setting the minimum heap size (-Xms) equal to the maximum heap size (-Xmx) to minimize garbage collections.* - quote from Oracle.